# Change figure numbering

Tags: floats, numbering, subfloats

I have a 6 subfigures in an figure environment and they are currently numbered a),b),c) etc. I would like to number them ai), bi), aii), bii) etc. Basically I'm looking for more control on the numbering, I've found stuff on how to change style of numbering but not to completely customise it. Can anyone help? Thanks Jack

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem: on which basis should the numeration change from `bi)` to `aii)`?. Furthermore, we don't usually put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts: it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: If you use a tabular instead of subfigure you can make any sort of captions you want.

Answer (score 1):

Technically you can adjust sub-caption numbering in whichever way you like. If the structure is too fine-tuned to be described in an automated way, adjust them manually:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{ai}
  \subcaptionbox{1}{\includegraphics[width=.15\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{bi}
  \subcaptionbox{2}{\includegraphics[width=.15\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
  \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{aii}
  \subcaptionbox{3}{\includegraphics[width=.15\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{bii}
  \subcaptionbox{4}{\includegraphics[width=.15\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
  \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{aiii}
  \subcaptionbox{5}{\includegraphics[width=.15\linewidth]{example-image-a}}
  \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{biii}
  \subcaptionbox{6}{\includegraphics[width=.15\linewidth]{example-image-b}}
  \caption{A caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The format of the sub-captions can be adjusted independent from the numeration.

Another option would be to forego the help provided by [`subcaption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) and create your own layout using a `tabular` (say) inside the `figure` environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\subcaptionstyle}{\small}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ *{6}{c} }
    \includegraphics[width=.15\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=.15\linewidth]{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics[width=.15\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=.15\linewidth]{example-image-b} &
    \includegraphics[width=.15\linewidth]{example-image-a} &
    \includegraphics[width=.15\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\
    \subcaptionstyle (ai) 1 &
    \subcaptionstyle (bi) 2 &
    \subcaptionstyle (aii) 3 &
    \subcaptionstyle (bii) 4 &
    \subcaptionstyle (aiii) 5 &
    \subcaptionstyle (biii) 6
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{A caption}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The former approach allows for cross-referencing like any other document element (like `figure`, or `table`). The latter doesn't, of course.